# Directional derivatives — implied continuity or not?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Consider the function :
>   $$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , (x,y) \mapsto
>   \begin{cases}
>         0 & \text{for } (x,y)=(0,0) \\
>    \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(y-x)^3}       & \text{for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)
>   \end{cases} $$
>   Is it differentiable and continuous at $0$?

I calculated the directional derivative which is equal to $0$ for all $u$ not equal to $0$. If all directional derivatives equal to $0$, does this imply differentiability and continuity? I cannot seem to find an answer online. But, if not, then how would i find if it is differentiable or not?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. Even if a function has a directional derivative for any direction, the possibility that the function is not continuous is still opened. The idea is that the directional derivative only captures the behavior of a function at a point *along a line*, so it could fail to catch its continuity or differentiability along other curves.

For example, consider
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2} & \text{if }(x,y)\neq(0,0), \\ 0 & \text{if }(x,y)=(0,0).\end{cases}$$
and take $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$. Then $f(t,t^2)=\frac{1}{2}$. However, $f$ has a directional derivative at the origin for any direction.

---

In the case of your function, take $(x,y)=(t,t^2+t)$. Then
$$f(t,t^2+t) = \frac{t^4(t+1)^2}{t^4(t+1)^2+t^6}=\frac{1}{1+t^2(1+t)^{-1}}.$$
It tends to $1$ if $t\to 0$. However, $f(0,0)=0$, so $f$ is not even continuous at the origin.

Comment: I think, Even the directional derivative does not exist with respect to the vector $u=(h,h)$

Comment: @Gune You are right in the case of the given function. I need to replace the example.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: The directional derivative does not exist with respect to the vector $u=(h,h)$ for $h\neq0$.

Proof:

$\begin{split}f'(0,u)&=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0)}{t}\\
&=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{\frac{t^4h^4}{t^4h^4+t^3(h-h)^3}-0}{t}\\
&=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{1}{t}\\
\end{split}$

This limit does not exist. Hense $f$ is not differentiable at(0,0).